# Как сделать показ подстраниц в django-cms 3.6.0?

Tags: django-cms

Есть раздел /blog/  с подстраницами post1, post2 etc. Как сделать показ post1, post2  и прочих на странице /blog ? Ни одна из инструкций найденных в поисковиках по запросам "subpages" и "pagination" не работает.

Comment: Читайте раздел [Menus and navigation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/navigation.html) документации по CMS. Там всё предельно просто.

Comment: Этот раздел про настройку меню. С его помощью можно сделать вставку ссылок на страницу. Мне нужна вставка содержимого подстраниц.

Comment: Страницы, как следует из их названия, показываются на отдельных страницах. Если вам надо сделать ленту блога, то читать надо раздел про то, [как django-приложения подключать к CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/apphooks.html).